# Why does the dynamic binding of following code seem not to work?

Tags: java, method-call, dynamic-binding, static-binding

This code's output is "test of X", but it's expected to be "test of Z".

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new X();
        x = new Z();
        x.test(1);
    }
}

class Y {
    public void test(double a) {
        System.out.println("test of Y");
    }
}

class X extends Y {
    public void test(double b) {
        System.out.println("test of X");
    }
}

class Z extends X {
    public void test(int c) {
        System.out.println("test of Z");
    }
}
```

I can't figure out whether it's static binding or dynamic binding. According to Core Java, when this method is called, what happens is following:

- List all the visible methods with the same name as this method, because test in X overrides that in Y, so it should be test in X. Only one candidate.
- Choose the most suitable one according to the type of argument, because test in X in the only candidate, so it must be chosen.
- If this method is private,  static, or final then it's static binding. Then resolution is done here. But it's not, so it should be dynamic binding here.
- At the run time, this method is actually called on an object of Z, so it looks up method table of Z, then test in Z should be called.

I don't know what where I take it wrong, the actual output is "test of X".

My OS: Windows 11 
My JDK: Java 20

Comment: To override it has to have the same signature (name and types of arguments).

Comment: You're calling through a variable of type `X`, and an `X` doesn't have a method `test(int)`, it only has `test(double)`. It is impossible for your code to call `test(int)` through that variable, even if the runtime type is `Z`. The compiler will bind to the method `test(double)`, and given `Z` doesn't override that, it will cal the one from `X`.

Comment: I found that if I change the parameter type of test() in class Z from int to double, the output becomes "test of Z"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so this is actually static binding here? @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: It doesn't work because you're overloading the methods instead of overriding them.

Comment: Thank you so much, and I want to know more about why it's working like this way? @esQmo_

Comment: Or can I say that dynamic binding only happens when this method is extended ?

Comment: Selection of *overloaded* methods is determined at compile time (“static binding”). Selection of *overridden* methods is determined at run time (“dynamic binding”). Class `Z` *overloads* the `test` method (because it declares it with a different signature).